# Embedded CASE with expressions in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, expression

Hi SQL SVR 2008 gurus.

As  a SQL newbie, I'm hoping for some direction.I've got a SELECT statement that needs to check an expression against a field value for each worker to see if they qualify for a paid lunch break. The value of the number of hours they need to work is in their workers table profile in a field called minimumhours, and I get their hours worked from an expression against a login and logout field in a table called workflow. The statement I've pieced together is as follows (the startdate and enddate will be user selectable values):

```
    DECLARE @StartDate AS DateTime
    SET @StartDate = CAST('03/25/2012' AS DATE)
    DECLARE @EndDate AS DateTime
    SET @EndDate = CAST('03/31/2012' AS DATE)

     SELECT 
     w.Firstname 
    ,w.Lastname 
    ,wf.Login
    ,wf.logout
    ,ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, wf.Login, wf.Logout) AS DECIMAL)/60,2) AS [Hours]
    ,w.LunchDeduction AS [Lunch Deduction]
    CASE [HoursBilled] = 
      WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, wf.Login, wf.Logout) < wf.MinimumHours THEN      
         ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, wf.Login, wf.Logout) AS DECIMAL)/60,-           
          w.LunchDeduction,2) 
      WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, wf.Login, wf.Logout) >= wf.MinimumHours THEN 
          ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, wf.Login, wf.Logout) AS DECIMAL)/60,- 0,2) 
    END
    FROM Workers AS w 
    JOIN Workflow AS wf 
    ON wf.LoggedInWorkerid = w.ID 
    JOIN Roles AS r
    ON w.RoleID = r.RoleID
    WHERE (r.Descript = 'Hourly')
    AND wf.Login >= @StartDate AND wf.Logout <= @EndDate
```

I've not seen any examples that seemed to fit my requirements, and was hoping

Comment: what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DateTime
SET @StartDate = CAST('03/25/2012' AS DATE)
DECLARE @EndDate AS DateTime
SET @EndDate = CAST('03/31/2012' AS DATE)

 SELECT 
 w.Firstname 
,w.Lastname 
,wf.Login
,wf.logout
,ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, wf.Login, wf.Logout) AS DECIMAL)/60,2) AS [Hours]
,w.LunchDeduction AS [Lunch Deduction]
,ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MI, wf.Login, wf.Logout) AS DECIMAL)/60,2) 
- CASE 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, wf.Login, wf.Logout) < wf.MinimumHours THEN      
     w.LunchDeduction
  ELSE
 0
END AS [HoursBilled]
FROM Workers AS w 
JOIN Workflow AS wf 
ON wf.LoggedInWorkerid = w.ID 
JOIN Roles AS r
ON w.RoleID = r.RoleID
WHERE (r.Descript = 'Hourly')
AND wf.Login >= @StartDate AND wf.Logout <= @EndDate
```

There was a comma missing before case statement, and mathematic was a bit strange. It seems to me that you intended to substract w.LunchDeduction from hours billed in case worker put less than wf.MinimumHours into hi/hers job, but instead you used that info as a precision parameter to round function.

Comment: Thank you Nikola. This works well and can see the syntax now of the CASE statement more clearly. I will be posting another related question, that has to do with the ROUNDING. The CEO here wants some specific rounding rules applied. Thank you again and perhaps you can help me with my next post :)

Comment: As an add on to this question, is there a way to output a field if the w.lunchdeduction is 0?

Comment: You are welcome. As for additional question, I did not understand it. If you mean if you could return a column under certain condition only then no, you can not. Columns are fixed in select list; you can change values only, with the exception of PIVOT and UNPIVOT queries.

Comment: Hi Nikola. I'm looking over your post on the question (which obviously evolved). It looks great. I'm testing it out and will leave a comment there. Thx again.